# Why is function overloading between member functions and non-member functions not allowed?

Tags: c++, overloading

In the following code:

```
void overload() {}
struct Struct {
    void overload(int arg1) {}
    void member() {
        overload(1); //compiles
        overload(); //error: too few arguments [...] did you mean '::overloaded'?
    }
};
```

If I change `struct` to `namespace` I get similar results, just with a slightly different error message.

Why can the compiler not select the non-member function via operator overloading when there is a member function with the same name?

For reference, all of the following cases work as expected:

- choosing between two non-members from a non-member (obviously)
- choosing between two members from a member
- choosing between two non-members from a member

Comment: The short answer is because this is how C++ works. The lookup rules for overload resolution are structured and rigid. Each scope is tried, step by step. When a matching symbol is found, in a scope, overload resolution takes place. If overload resolution fails, the code is ill-formed, and lookup does not continue. ADL introduces some intricacies, but that's a capsule summary. Perhaps someone can provide a capsule summary of the relevant quotes from the standard... But this is simply how C++ works, that's it.

Comment: Is there an actual reason why the standard is written that way, or is it just a language design oversight?

Comment: put `using ::overload;` inside `member`.  It's an intentional decision, you wouldn't want the behaviour of `member()` to change if you happened to include some other header before this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mostly asking *why* so rather than saying "because the language says so", lets show an example where your suggestion causes everything to fail.

Suppose I have a handy class in my github repo:

```
struct HandyClass {
    void display(short c) {
        std::cout << c;
    }
    void doStuff() {
        display(3);
    }
};
```

And then some other developer in a different github repro makes a handy set of display functions:

```
void display(double v) {
    showWindowsPopup("Your score was %f", v);
}
void display(int v) {
    showWindowsPopup("Your score was %d", v);
}
```

You download both repros, and suddenly, HandyClass doesn't work right anymore:

```
#include "displays.h"
#include "handyclass.h"

int main() {
    HandyClass a;
    a.doStuff(); //Why does this show a windows popup!?!?
}
```

Because you included the display headers first, then `display(3)` matched to `::display(int)` instead of `::HandyClass::display(short)`, because `3` is an `int`. And much sadness occurs.

But with the official C++ lookup rules, this doesn't happen.  Since my class has `display` functions, it will ignore functions outside the class, to prevent mistakes, so that `HandyClass` always does the same thing for everyone.

Comment: While this reasoning makes sense, I'm disturbed by the fact that it applies just as well when there are no structs, classes, or namespaces involved at all.

Comment: @Stuntddude You mean if someone adds a random method to the global namespace? Yes. In fact, that is _why_ we have namespaces. It's also why Java banned global methods.  Also why microsofts `#define max` is super annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Because the name `overload` in global scope can't be found by [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup), it's hidden by `Struct::overload`. It has no chance to participate in overload resolution which happens later.

(emphasis mine)

> name lookup examines the scopes as described below, until it finds at least one declaration of any kind, **at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are examined**.